# 2d scala array iteration

Tags: arrays, scala

I have a 2d array of type boolean (not important)
It is easy to iterate over the array in non-functional style.
How to do it FP style?

```
var matrix = Array.ofDim[Boolean](5, 5)
```

for ex, I would like to iterate through all the rows for a given column and return a list of int that would match a specific function.
Example: for column 3, iterate through rows 1 to 5 to return 4, 5 if the cell at (4, 3), (5, 3) match a specif function. Thx v much

```
def getChildren(nodeId: Int) : List[Int] = {
    info("getChildren("+nodeId+")")

    var list = List[Int]()
    val nodeIndex = id2indexMap(nodeId)

    for (rowIndex <- 0 until matrix.size) {
      val elem = matrix(rowIndex)(nodeIndex)
      if (elem) {
        println("Row Index = " + rowIndex)
        list = rowIndex :: list
      }
    }

    list
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about

```
(1 to 5) filter {i => predicate(matrix(i)(3))}
```

where `predicate` is your function?

Note that initialized with (5,5) indexes goes from 0 to 4.

**Update**: based on your  example

```
def getChildren(nodeId: Int) : List[Int] = {
  info("getChildren("+nodeId+")")
  val nodeIndex = id2indexMap(nodeId)

  val result = (0  until matrix.size).filter(matrix(_)(nodeIndex)).toList
  result.forEach(println)
  result
}
```

You may move the print in the fiter if you want too, and reverse the list if you want it exactly as in your example

Comment: I think your sol would return an array if the initial structure is a 2d array?

Comment: Ah, another difference is I was thinking about filtering directly on the 2d array, but by doing so, I am loosing the row index: val children = matrix.filter(row => row(nodeIndex)) which returns 2 1d arrays - but I do not know which one

Comment: Not really, the structure I do fitering on is a Range, not an Array (as it was the indexes you wanted in the output). The result type is an  IndexedSeq[Int], and it happens to be a Vector.  Just do .toList if you want a List, but Vector is usually a better structure than List.

Comment: This is the non-FP version of what I'd like to achieve (edit main)

Answer (score 2):

If you're not comfortable with filters and zips, you can stick with the for-comprehension but use it in a more functional way:

```
for {
  rowIndex <- matrix.indices
  if matrix(rowIndex)(nodeIndex)
} yield { 
  println("Row Index = " + rowIndex)
  rowIndex
}
```

`yield` builds a new collection from the results of the for-comprehension, so this expression evaluates to the collection you want to return. `seq.indices` is a method equivalent to `0 until seq.size`. The curly braces allow you to span multiple lines without semicolons, but you can make it in-line if you want:

```
for (rowIndex <- matrix.indices; if matrix(rowIndex)(nodeIndex)) yield rowIndex
```

Should probably also mention that normally if you're iterating through an Array you won't need to refer to the indices at all. You'd do something like

```
for {
  row  <- matrix 
  elem <- row
} yield f(elem)
```

but your use-case is a bit unusual in that it requires the indices of the elements, which you shouldn't normally be concerned with (using array indices is essentially a quick and dirty hack to pair a data element with a number). If you want to capture and use the notion of position you might be better off using a `Map[Int, Boolean]` or a `case class` with such a field.

Answer (score 1):

```
def findIndices[A](aa: Array[Array[A]], pred: A => Boolean): Array[Array[Int]] =
  aa.map(row => 
    row.zipWithIndex.collect{ 
      case (v,i) if pred(v) => i 
  }
)
```

You can refactor it to be a bit more nicer by extracting the function that finds the indices in a single row only:

```
def findIndices2[A](xs: Array[A], pred: A => Boolean): Array[Int] =
  xs.zipWithIndex.collect{ 
    case (v,i) if pred(v) => i 
  }
```

And then write

```
matrix.map(row  => findIndices2(row, pred))
```